# How can I return a file using react? Or `npm unload` analogs for express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, npm, sendfile

How can I return a file using react? In express, this is sendFile. If the file is exe, then it will be downloaded, if it is a pdf file, then it will be displayed in the browser, if the picture, then it will also be displayed.
I would like to know how you can implement the same feed using react.
Or, perhaps express has the same library as `unload` for react. So that you can track when the user leaves the page

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant option, but effective.
Use `<iframe>` to make the document full screen, indicate the following:

```css
iframe {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:999999;
}
```